# How to format protobuf class instance to json string without unknown fields?

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

> **Question Background**

I use this library provided by google to format protobuf class instance to json string.

available api usage: `JsonFormat.printToString(docInfo)`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.protobuf-java-format</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java-format</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

**But I encountered a very tricky situation.**

Because this library would automatically add protobuf class instance's unknown fields to the json object, and then they will be decoded as string text as the corresponding values.

Because we do not know the type of unknown fields, so the straightforward string text encode method could trigger very serious result!!!

`{"code": 1,"msg": "","code1": 2, "4": [3]}`

Such as this key "4".

Could someone tell me how to format pb class instance to json text string without the unknown fields?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The class `JsonFormat` of `com.googlecode.protobuf.format` does not ignore unknown fields.

A work-around is to use `protobuf-java-format 1.3` (or higher) and create a class that extends `JsonFormat` and overrides the method [`protected void print(Message message, JsonGenerator generator) throws IOException`](https://github.com/bivas/protobuf-java-format/blob/1.3/src/main/java/com/googlecode/protobuf/format/JsonFormat.java#L95).

You can use the class below (in scala).

With this class, you will get the following json by calling `printToString(message=<your_message>)`:

```
{"code": 1,"msg": "","code1": 2}
```

---

```
import com.google.protobuf.Message
import com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat
import com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat.JsonGenerator
import java.util.Iterator
/** A JsonFormat class that ignore unknown fields.
 *
 *  Example of use: You have a protobuf message, called message, and you want 
 *  to get the json presentation as string with ignoring unknown fields:
 *  val jsonFormatExtension: JsonFormatExtension = new JsonFormatExtension()
 *  val jsonStr: String = jsonFormatExtension.printToString(message=message)
 */
class JsonFormatExtension extends JsonFormat {
  override def print(message: Message, generator: JsonGenerator):Unit = {
    var iter = message.getAllFields().entrySet().iterator()
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      var field = iter.next()
      printField(field.getKey(), field.getValue(), generator)
      if (iter.hasNext()) {
        generator.print(",")
      }
    }
    // disable printing unknown fields
    // if (message.getUnknownFields().asMap().size() > 0)
    //   generator.print(", ")
    // printUnknownFields(message.getUnknownFields(), generator)
  }
}
```